# How to remove Left property when position: absolute?

Tags: css, css-position

I'm overriding the site CSS to an RTL version when specific language is chosen.

I have an element which has to have absolute positioning. In the LTR version, I do `left: 0px;` and it's aligned to the left; in the RTL version I want to do the opposite with `right`, but the `left` property isn't overridden so it still stays to the left.

- I've tried hacking with `!important`, but that didn't work.
- I've tried setting `left: none`, but that didn't work.

How can I either set it to none or remove it completely while overriding?

Comment: To remove only a specific css attribute such as `left` use: `var cssObject = $('selector').prop('style'); cssObject.removeProperty('left');`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left is described. Initial value is auto

Comment: if you got here looking for a way to remove some property in tailwind when using different breakpoints, it is `md:left-[unset]`

Answer (score 353, accepted):

```
left:auto;
```

This will default the `left` back to the browser default.

---

So if you have your Markup/CSS as:

```
<div class="myClass"></div>

.myClass
{
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
}
```

When setting RTL, you could change to:

```
<div class="myClass rtl"></div>

.myClass
{
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
}
.myClass.rtl
{
  left:auto;
  right:0;
}
```

Answer (score 28):

In the future one would use `left: unset;` for unsetting the value of left.

As of today 4 nov 2014 `unset` is only supported in Firefox.

[Read more about unset in MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset)

My guess is we'll be able to use it around year 2022 when IE 11 is properly phased out.

Comment: IE puts the "IE" in "I'llnever dIE."

Comment: In the end of year  2017 Microsoft Edge build 10565+  supports it

Comment: Just used this for clearing a `right` position for responsive change - worked perfectly (in Chrome)

Comment: get my upvote for the 2022 prediction

Answer (score 2):

```
left: initial
```

This will also set `left` back to the browser default.

But important to know `property: initial` is not supported in IE.