# tailwind position absolute on smaller screens and right on bigger

Tags: css, css-position, tailwind-css

I have menu that I would like to be positioned to left of the screen when screen is small (let say before SM) and positioned to right when bigger.

```
<MenuItems
  class="
    absolute left-2 top-24 w-full mt-8
    sm:right-2 sm:top-0 sm:w-max
  "
>
```

Settings for `right-*` works as expected when applied alone, however when prefixed with breakpoint `sm` `left-*` is taking priority.

Is it a way to use something that would cancel left on bigger screens? like `sm:left-none`

Comment: Based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245729/how-to-remove-left-property-when-position-absolute I find that `sm:left-auto` would work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove Left property when position: absolute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245729/how-to-remove-left-property-when-position-absolute)

Answer (score 6):

Yes `auto` can be used to cancel positioning values. So use `sm:left-auto`.

Another (worse) option would be to use `right-full` on smaller screens. But then your element would be offscreen. Though you could transform it back like this: `right-full translate-x-full sm:right-0 sm:translate-x-0`